# Compare site traffic to Dedicated machine time usage

Tags: web-hosting, cloud-hosting

If I have a website, hosted with a standard hosting company, and I would like to move it to a Dedicated machine, maybe EC2, is there a way to compare my current traffic to usage of a cloud machine? 
Hosting companies gives you plan measured in Bandwith/Space while EC2 in usage time.

So I'm looking for a way to predict machine usage time based on my current traffic data for costs evaluation.

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you're understanding usage time correctly.  For your website to exist on EC2, you'll need to create one or more instances depending on the architecture you use.  This is the same as a dedicated hosting setup elsewhere except with cloud instances.

The difference lies with billing.  Where a traditional hosting company will charge you monthly, EC2 charges you per instance hour, or every hour you have an instance running.  Therefore, for hosting a website, you'll have the server running 24/7 which will equate to roughly 720 hrs a month charged at a few cents per hour.

The key thing to work out is how many/what size instances you'll need to run your site at the equivalent performance you're seeing now, and that's only something you'll figure out with testing.